# Type of model for space-characters recovery?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, keras

I have the string "Ihaveadog" and i need to recover space-characters in the string.I tried to use seq2seq model but failed.In my case i've got data like "Ihaveadog" -> "010000101000" encoded by one-hot method.What type of DL model is good for the task or the best way is the using classic ML methods?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: An excellent question! This problem is called *word spacing/segmentation*; cf. e.g., _A Language Independent n-Gram Model for Word Segmentation_ or _Automatic word spacing using probabilistic models based on character n-grams_. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261 Welcome to the site!